# initializing vector with pair

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I'm having trouble initializing vectors with pairs; My code doesn't seem to work, result of adj_list[0][0].first doesn't show *1*:

```
vector < vector <pair <int, int> > > adj_list;
adj_list.insert(adj_list.end(), { { (make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5)), (make_pair(1,7),make_pair(0,2)) }});
```

What i'm trying to do is to create an adjacency list (hardcoded), with this structure:

> adj_list[0] ---- make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5)
>
> adj_list[1] ---- make_pair(0,7),make_pair(3,9)

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: `(x, y)` <=> `operator,(x, y)`

Comment: adj_list.insert(adj_list.end(), { { (make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5))}, {(make_pair(1,7),make_pair(0,2))} });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong brackets, which makes `(make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5))` use the comma operator and its value is `make_pair(2,5)`.

You should use curly brackets:

```
adj_list.insert(adj_list.end(), { { {make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5)}, {make_pair(1,7),make_pair(0,2)} }});
```

But, on the other hand: that's not an *initialisation*.
The vector has already been initialised to the empty vector.

This is an initialisation (you also don't need `make_pair`):

```
vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adj_list = {{{1, 20}, {2,5}},
                                           {{1, 7}, {0, 2}}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), the correct syntax to *insert* (not initialize) would be

```
adj_list.insert(adj_list.end(), { 
                                 { make_pair(1,20), make_pair(2,5) }, 
                                 { make_pair(1,7),  make_pair(0,2) } 
                                });
```